# How to make a function render a list item

Tags: react-native

I have 2 classes that are FlatListItem and HobbyList to display a list of hobby. But now i want use just one class HobbyList . I want to make a function `renderItem` in class HobbyList to render like class FlatListItem. How can I do that?

```js
class FlatListItem extends Component {
render() {
        const { checked } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.children}>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() => this.onClick(checked)}>
                        <Image source={this.props.item} style={styles.image} ></Image>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.checkbox}>
                    <CheckBox
                        checked={checked}
                        onPress={() => this.onClick(checked)}
                    >
                    </CheckBox>
                </View>
                <Text>{this.props.item.name}</Text>
            </View>

        );
    }
}
export default class HobbyList extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    renderItem({item,index}){
        //render list here
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.flexParent}>
                <View></View>
                <View style={styles.parent}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={formatData(flatListData, numColumns)}
                        numColumns={numColumns}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => {
                            if (item.empty === true) {
                                return <View style={[styles.children, 
                                  styles.itemVisible]}></View>
                            }
                            return <FlatListItem item={item}> 
                            </FlatListItem>
                        }}
                    ></FlatList>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to cover `renderItem` as a function. Then you don't have to classify it as a `class`. You can make a `function` and use it.

```js
this.state = { checked: true }
...
  _renderItem = ({item}) => (
            <View style={styles.children}>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() => this.onClick(checked)}>
                        <Image source={item.image} style={styles.image} ></Image>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.checkbox}>
                    <CheckBox
                        checked={checked}
                        onPress={() => this.onClick(checked)}
                    >
                    </CheckBox>
                </View>
                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
  );
...
      <FlatList
        ...
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
      />
```